# Pymongo, How to find edit distance of field value and a input string

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to find the similarity between two sequences, for this i am using edit distance. Since I hav very large data, I am using mongodb database
My data is of the form

```
{
    "POS": "*",
    "MAPQ": "0",
    "`SEQ": "AGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGCTAGGGTTAGGGTAAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTATGGTTAGGGTTAGTGGTAGGGTTAGGTTTAGGGG"
},

{
    "POS": "*",
    "MAPQ": "0",
    "`SEQ": "TAGGGTTAGTGGTAGGGTTAGGTTTAGGGG""
},
```

Here if I input a seq = "GATAGAAACCCTAACCCTCTAACCCTAACCCTCTAACCCTAACCCTCTAACCCTAACCCTATAGGGTTAGTGGTAGGGTTAGGTTTAGGGG"

```
for doc in fastqseq.find({}, {'SEQ':1,'_id':0}):
            print  doc
            ed = edit_distance(doc,seq)
            print ed
```

For the above code, the output I get
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/metrics/distance.py", line 61, in edit_distance
    _edit_dist_step(lev, i+1, j+1, s1[i], s2[j])
KeyError: 0

Any suggestion is appreciated

output of print doc

```
{u'SEQ': u'ATCTGATATCCTGGAAAAGCACCCACACCCCCAGGTGAGCATCTGACAGCCTGGAACAGCATCCACAACCCCAGGTGAACATCCGACAGCCTGAAGCAGAA'}
{u'SEQ': u'TGTTCCAGGCTGTCAGAGGCTCACCTGGGCGGGGGGGGGCTGTTTCAGTCTGTCAGATGCTCCCCTGGGGGGGGGGGTTCTGTTCCAGGCTGCAGGATGCT'}
{u'SEQ': u'GGGGGTGTGGGTGCTGTTCCAGGCCGTCAGATGCTCACTTGGGGGTGCAGGGTGCTGTTCCAGTCTGTCAGATGCTCACCTGGGGGTGTGGGTTGTGTTCC'}
```

Comment: My guess is `edit_distance` takes two strings, and you appear to be giving it a document? Make sure that you give it two strings. Also, are you sure you want to be using vanilla levenstein distance for DNA data? Maybe have a look at Damerau-levenstein, or needleman-wunsch algorithms.

Comment: Thank you rafalio, i am very new to mongodb and pymongo, still trying to figure out how things work. but with my problem, the doc is a cursor and out puts one record at a time(hope my understanding is completely wrong), but I don't know how to retrieve only the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare one string to another. `doc` is a dictionary, so you can't use it like you are using it.

Untested, but this general idea should work work:

```
docs = fastqseq.find({}, {'SEQ':1,'_id':0})

for d1 in docs:
  for d2 in docs:
    distance = edit_distance(d1['SEQ'],d2['SEQ'])
    // use the distance variable here
```